# WTForms FileField has no 'filename' attribute

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, filefield

I am creating a website with Python Flask. However, when the user registers an account, I get this error:

```
'FileField' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

I have used the 'filename' attribute in my 'save_picture' function below:

```
def save_picture(form_picture):
form = UpdateAccountForm()
random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
_, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form.picture.filename)
picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/profile_pics', 'picture_fn')

output_size = (125,125)
i = Image.open(form_picture)
i.thumbnail(output_size)
i.save(picture_path)

form_picture.save(picture_path)

return picture_fn
```

This is the form that I have used the 'FileField' object in:

```
class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
age = IntegerField('Age', validators=[DataRequired()])
picture = FileField('Update Profile Picture', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
submit = SubmitField('Update')

def validate_username(self, username):
    if username.data != current_user.username:
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose a different one')

def validate_email(self, email):
    if email.data != current_user.email:
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That email is taken. Please choose a different one.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the input field itself. In order to access the sent data, the input field has an attribute called `data`. If you take this into account, the assignment would look like this.

`_, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form.picture.data.filename)`

The code for your endpoint will then look something like this.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # ...
        random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(form.picture.data.filename)
        img = Image.open(form.picture.data)
        img.thumbnail((125,125))
        img.save(os.path.join(
            app.static_folder,
            'profile_pics',
            f'{random_hex}{ext}'
        ))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```